# Varying the Parameter List of an Function Based on Template Parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost, template-meta-programming

I am trying to create a template class that executes a user-specified **N**-ary function with arguments of type **C**. To do so, I need some way of specifying the type of this function based on the template parameters. The following code illustrates my problem:

```
template <typename C, size_t N>
class NaryDispatch {

    typedef typename std::function<void(/* N parameters of type C& */)> NaryFn;

    public:
        NaryDispatch(NaryFn f) : m_function(std::forward<NaryFn>(f)) {}

    private:
        NaryFn m_function;
};
```

I have been unable to find a way to build the std::function type with a signature of the appropriate arity. I am using C++11 and Boost::MPL extensively so solutions involving either are more than welcome. I have tried to use SFINAE/template parameter deduction on the constructor parameter as follows:

```
template <
    class... Args,
    typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) == N, C>::type = 0
>
NaryDispatch(std::function<void(Args&...)> fn) : m_function(std::forward<???>(fn)) {}
```

As you can see, the issue here is that because I have been unable to determine the type the function will take given the template parameters **C** and **N**, I'm unable to determine the type of the class member where the function should be stored.

To simplify my intent a bit, for template parameters **C** and **N**, the class constructor should accept (and store in a private member) an `std::function` that returns `void` and accepts **N** parameters of type `C&`. For example, the following should compile:

```
NaryDispatch<int, 3> disp([](int a, int b, int c) {});
```

Thanks in advance for any insights you might offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shouldn't be too hard. Let's start with the top level:

```
template <typename C, std::size_t N>
struct NaryDispatch
{
    // details, see below

    using f_type = typename function_maker<C &, N>::type;

    template <typename F>
    NaryDispatch(F && f) : fn_(std::forward<F>(f)) {}

    f_type fn_;
};
```

Now we just need to implement the trait `function_maker`:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t K, typename ...Args>
struct function_maker
{
    using type = typename function_maker<T, K - 1, T, Args...>::type;
};

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
struct function_maker<T, 0, Args...>
{
    using type = std::function<void(Args...)>;
};
```

Finally, you might also want to provide some kind of constrained call function. Perhaps like this:

```
template <typename ...Args,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) == N>::type>
void run(Args &&... args)
{
    fn_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Change `Args...` to `Args&...` since he wants references.

Comment: You can do this in many ways; another idea is to use `make_index_sequence` and expand some pack like `Foo<T, I>...` with `template <typename T, std::size_t I> using Foo = T;`.

Comment: I couldn't get `C&` to work for some reason. Replacing the second `T` parameter to `function_maker` to `T&` in the primary template worked, as did changing `Args...` to `Args&...` in the specialization.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Not sure what you mean, it seems to [work as expected](http://ideone.com/JJLDUM) for me.

Comment: Probably just a small mistake on my part, I see it working in your demo.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Works exactly as intended and a very elegant solution to boot. Unfortunately, in my shortsightedness, I forgot to consider how exactly I might invoke this function if it has an arbitrary number of parameters. The goal would be to supply the parameters by selecting N elements from a container at run-time. I immediately went looking for some form of "currying" support but found nothing. Oh well, perhaps an issue for another question.

Thanks again!

Comment: @DaveStance What was the `N` template parameter for if you wanted to know the arguments at runtime?

Comment: @0x499602D2, it specifies the arity of the function. The user should be able to specify a function taking N arguments of the specified type, at runtime the intention was to take N elements of an std::vector and invoke the function with these elements as the arguments.

Comment: @DaveStance Correct me if I'm wrong, but the user can specify the number of parameters with `N`, and then calling the function would be as simple as passing in the elements of the vector `func(v[0], v[1], ...)`, correct?

Comment: @0x499602D2, indeed that's what I'm going for. The issue is the "..." however. Is there a way to expand an arbitrary selection of a vector elements based on a template parameter?

Comment: @DaveStance I don't think that's possible since the size of the vector isn't known at compile time, there's no way you can unpack a parameter pack `v[I]...` without knowing the size of `v` beforehand.

Comment: @DaveStance Maybe you can use iterators instead and have your `fn_` function be function template that takes two template arguments as iterators. Then you can pass in your range without writing out every argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64522/discussion-between-davestance-and-0x499602d2).

Answer (score 0):

Your next problem will be "How do I pass N parameters to the contained `std::function`?" I think you could simplify substantially by using a dispatcher class template that works with any old list of parameter types:

```
template <typename...Args>
class Dispatcher {
    typedef typename std::function<void(Args...)> Fn;

    public:
        Dispatcher(Fn f) : m_function(std::move(f)) {}

        void operator()(Args...args) {
          m_function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

    private:
        Fn m_function;
};
```

along with a bit of metaprogramming to calculate the proper `Dispatcher` specialization to handle N parameters of type `C&`:

```
template <typename C, size_t N, typename...Args>
struct NaryDispatch_ {
  using type = typename NaryDispatch_<C, N-1, Args..., C&>::type;
};
template <typename C, typename...Args>
struct NaryDispatch_<C, 0, Args...> {
  using type = Dispatcher<Args...>;
};

template <typename C, size_t N>
using NaryDispatch = typename NaryDispatch_<C, N>::type;
```

**[DEMO AT IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Vzy7m1)**